# How to show a different price value and currency based on the country

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app aiming to manage a collection (like pokemon cards). It has JSON data with different variables, in which, the price. To display the list of all items I do the following:

```
    struct itemRow: View {
let items: [Item] = Bundle.main.decode("item.json")

 var body: some View {
List {
         ForEach(items) { item in
             HStack {
                Text(item.name)
                 Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", item.price))€")
                    }
                }
           }
        }
}
```

Which creates a straightforward list with names and prices stacked one on top of the other. My issue is that the original data are in €, so when the user uses the app whenever he is in the world, he will see Euro prices. I wanted to do something like an 'if, else' statement or whatever works, to make the user see the correct price even if he has USD. I was able only to show different currencies in the text, like '90$' instead of '90€', but the right conversion is like '97.69$'. I know that rates change every day, but due to the simple app, even some static constants are good enough for my purpose. I would like to support GBP and USD, not every currency

Comment: You would have to create your own version to keep the currencies and multiply them. You haven't provided enough information to help you troubleshoot your own setup.

Comment: Why do you need to do any conversion? If a user enters their own value in USD then simply show that value in USD. If a user enters their own value in GBP, then simply show that value in GBP. Is a user going to want to see the value they entered in different currencies?

Comment: Is your question about how to do the conversion, or how to present it correctly on the UI?

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I wasn't clear with my question so I edited it. I hope now it's clearer, but I Explain even further if needed

Comment: What about changing `item.price` with `item.price * exchangerate`, and defining `exchangerate` based on the preferences of the user with the correct value? (a default value of `1` for displaying in EURO's)

Answer (score -1):

I solved in this way, basing the if-else statement on the Locale

```swift
struct itemRow: View {
  let items: [Item] = Bundle.main.decode("item.json")
  let locale = Locale.current

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(items) { item in
        HStack {
          Text(item.name)

          if (locale.identifier == "en_US") {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", minifig.price * 1.10))$")
              .foregroundColor(.gray)
              .font(.system(size: 12))
          } else if (locale.identifier == "en_GB") {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", minifig.price * 0.88))£")
              .foregroundColor(.gray)
              .font(.system(size: 12))
          } else {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.2f", minifig.price))€")
              .foregroundColor(.gray)
              .font(.system(size: 12))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```